# Selector not fired without subscribe()

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I have two selectors:

- isLoggedIn -
- selectUserDetails

---

Which implementation looks like this:

```
export const selectAuthState = state => state.auth;

export const isLoggedIn = createSelector(
    selectAuthState,
    auth => auth.loggedIn
);

export const selectUserDetails = createSelector(
    selectAuthState,
    auth => auth.userDetails
);
```

Their state looks like this:

```
export interface State {
  loggedIn: boolean,
  userDetails: UserDetails
}

export const initialAuthState: State = {
  loggedIn: false,
  userDetails: undefined
};
```

I have a question about this line of code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(isLoggedIn)
    )

    this.userDetails$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(selectUserDetails)
    )
  }
```

This part of code is fine:

```
this.isLoggedIn$ = this.store.pipe(
          select(isLoggedIn)
        )
```

but this:

```
this.userDetails$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(selectUserDetails)
    )
```

is only fired with subscription..

```
this.store.pipe(
      select(selectUserDetails),
      map(...rest of code)
    ).subscribe();
```

In other parts of code I also cannot use this selectUserDetails selector without subscribe(). 
At first I thought that it is a problem with undefined variable but even if user is logged in and userDetails is populated in global State it still is not fired.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, you dont handle isLoggedIn in html file with async pipe?

Comment: There was a typo in my async pipe... Problem is solved. Anyway I treat your hint as an answer :)